# Existence of adjoint of the inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{F}$ and $V$ be an **inner product space** over $\mathbb{F}$.

Let $T:H\rightarrow V$ be a bounded linear bijection.

If $V$ is a Hilbert space, then the open mapping theorem implies that $T^{-1}$ is a bounded operator hence $T^{-1}$ has the adjoint. However, I'm curious about the case when $V$ is just an inner product space.

> Question 1
>
> Is $T^{-1}$ necessarily a bounded operator?
>
> Question 2
>
> Assuming $T^{-1}$ is a bounded operator, does $T^{-1}$ have the adjoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No. Let $H=\ell^2$, and let $V$ be the subspace of $\ell^2$ consisting of the sequences $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\sum n^2 |x_n|^2<\infty$. The subspace $V$ inherits the inner product from $H$. The operator sending $(x_n)$ to $(x_n/n)$ is bounded on $H$, and maps $H$ bijectively onto $V$. But its inverse is not bounded, since $T^{-1}(e_n)=ne_n$.
2. Yes. If $T^{-1}$ is bounded, then $V$ is isomorphic to $H$ and therefore is itself a Hilbert space. The usual construction of adjoint operator applies.

Comment: I don't get the Question2. How $V$ is a hilbert space? Would you give me some details?

Comment: Take a Cauchy sequence in V. Send it to H via the inverse operator. It's still Cauchy. Hence it has a limit. Send it back to V.